# How to change state value when input is checked with useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change the value of `isChecked` in state when checkbox is checked.

Here's my state:

```
const [talles, setTalles] = useState([
      { name: 'S', isChecked: false },
      { name: 'M', isChecked: false },
      { name: 'L', isChecked: false },
      { name: 'XL', isChecked: false },
])
```

For each element in this state an `<input type="checkbox" />` is created.

The thing is I want to dynamically change the `isChecked` property.

Normally I would do:

```
setProduct({
       ...product,
       [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
})
```

But that would only work if my state was like `useState({ productCheckbox: '' })`

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the previous state and change the value of the changing talle:

```
setTalles(previousState => previousState.map(talle => {
  if (talle.name === e.target.name) return ({
    ...talle,
    isChecked: e.target.checked,
  })
  return talle
}))
```

Or same but shorter:

```
setTalles(previousState => previousState.map(talle =>
  talle.name === e.target.name ?
    ({
      ...talle,
      isChecked: e.target.checked,
    })
    :
    talle
}))
```

Comment: Thank you! had to pass the `e` but it worked!

Comment: How could I make the checkbox checked if the state value is true?